# jsd3 audio playback on hover each text node

Tags: java, html, css

I created a jsd3 project with the help of google bard, but the code does not work, can you guys please help me out? I need to attach an audio file to each text node, when hover on each text the audio should be played back, the audio files are in a local folder called :audio>

here its the full code, thankyou in advance.

`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>JSD3 Chart with Audio</title>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="chart"></div>
<script>
var   w = 1000,
      h =  1000,
      circleWidth = 3; 
 
// Change the color to something more vrivant:
var palette = {
      "lightgray": "#E5E8E8",
      "gray": "#708284",
      "mediumgray": "#536870",
      "black":"#000000",
      "blue": "#3B757F"
  }

var colors = d3.scale.category20();

var nodes = [
      { name: "Borg", audio: "audio/borg.mp3"},
      { name: "HTML5", target: [0], value:1, audio: "audio/html5.mp3"},
      { name: "CSS3", target: [0], value: 1, audio: "audio/css3.mp3" },  
     
];

var links = [];

for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++){
      if (nodes[i].target !== undefined) { 
            for ( var x = 0; x < nodes[i].target.length; x++ ) 
              links.push({
                  source: nodes[i],
                  target: nodes[nodes[i].target[x]]  
              });
      };
};


var myChart = d3.select('#chart')
      .append("div")
        .classed("svg-container", true)
      
      .append('svg')
        .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMinYMin meet")
        .attr("viewBox", "0 0 1000 800")
        .classed("svg-content-responsive", true)


var force = d3.layout.force()
      .nodes(nodes)
      .links([])
      .gravity(0.1)
      .charge(-1000)
      .size([w,h]); 

      var link = myChart.selectAll('line') 
            .data(links).enter().append('line')
            .attr('stroke', palette.black)
            .attr('strokewidth', '1');

      var node =  myChart.selectAll('circle')  
            .data(nodes).enter() 
            .append('g') 
            .call(force.drag); 

     
     node.append('circle')
            .attr('cx', function(d){return d.x; })
            .attr('cy', function(d){return d.y; })
            .attr('r', function(d,i){
                  console.log("circle ",d.value,d);
                  if ( i > 0 ) {
                        return circleWidth + d.value; 
                  } else {
                        return circleWidth + 60; 
                  }
            })
            .attr('fill', function(d,i){
                  if ( i > 0 ) {
                        return colors(i);
                  } else {
                        return '#fff';
                  }
            })
            .attr('strokewidth', function(d,i){
                  if ( i > 0 ) {
                        return '0';
                  } else {
                        return '2';
                  }
            })
             .attr('stroke', function(d,i){
                  if ( i > 0 ) {
                        return '';
                  } else {
                        return 'black';
                  }
            })
            .on('mouseover', function(d){
                if ( d.audio ) {
                  var audio = new Audio(d.audio);
                  audio.play();
                }
            })
            .on('mouseout', function(d){
                if ( d.audio ) {
                  audio.pause();
                }
            });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

`

I try different ways to ask bard, i followed the code source links, i made several google search and could not find the answer.

Comment: by adding this link the audio its working OK...<script src ="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.14/d3.js"></script>

Comment: But now the chart is stuck at the top left corner, I added a css file and set it to top=200px; left{200px; I used the  div Id "chart" but it dint work, so how I get the chart to display at the center of the page?